# How to add 2 different taxonomies to Wordpress CPT permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have problem to add a second taxonomy to my cpt permalink structure.

With one register_taxonomy (pxlr-products-**category**) everything works fine and looks like this: https://example.com/products/my_category/my_productname

But I want a second register_taxonomy (pxlr-products-**status**). When I do that I see in my permalink instead of the tax slug just this %status% https://example.com/products/my_category/%status%/my_productname and I get an 404 error. Of cause I'ved flushed my permalinks

A second thing is, (pxlr-products-**status**) can have a value like (discontinued) but it is not a must, it can be empty as well

My permalinks should look like this https://example.com/products/my_category/my_status/my_productname

Or look like this https://example.com/products/my_category/my_productname

Here is my CPT, I can't find my error and need help, thanks :-/

```
class PXLR_Products
{

    function __construct(){

        // register post type
        add_action('init', array($this, 'register_products_post_type'));

        // register taxonomy
        add_action('init', array($this, 'register_products_taxonomy'));

        // slug - category filter
        add_filter('post_type_link', [$this,'products_post_link'], 1, 3 );
        
        // Rewrite support
        add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_rewrite_rules']);

    }

    function custom_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'products/(.+?)/?$',
            'index.php?pxlr-products-category=$matches[1]',
            'bottom');
        
        // add_rewrite_rule(
        //     'products/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$',
        //     'index.php?pxlr-products-category=$matches[1]&pxlr-products-status=$matches[2]',
        //     'bottom');
    }

    public function register_products_post_type()
    {

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Products', 'Post Type General Name', 'pxlr-products'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Products', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'pxlr-products'),
            'menu_name' => __('PXLR Products', 'pxlr-products'),
            'all_items' => __('All Products', 'pxlr-products'),
            'view_item' => __('Show product', 'pxlr-products'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add product', 'pxlr-products'),
            'add_new' => __('Add Product', 'pxlr-products'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit product', 'pxlr-products'),
            'update_item' => __('Update product', 'pxlr-products'),
            'search_items' => __('Search products', 'pxlr-products'),
            'not_found' => __('No products found', 'pxlr-products'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in trash.', 'pxlr-products'),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'name' => 'Products',
            'name_admin_bar' => 'Products',
            'singular_name' => 'Products',
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-microphone',
            'label' => __('Products', 'pxlr-products'),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
            'menu_position' => 28,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'),
            'rest_base' => 'products',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'has_archive' => 'products',
            'can_export' => false,
            'taxonomies' => array('pxlr-products-category', 'pxlr-products-status'),
            'publicaly_queryable' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,

            //'rewrite' => ['slug' => _x('products/%category%', 'Post Type Slug', 'pxlr-products'), 'with_front' => true ], // for one taxonomy if working fine!!!!
            'rewrite' => ['slug' => _x('products/%category%/%status%', 'Post Type Slug', 'pxlr-products'), 'with_front' => true ], // for two taxonomies
            'template_lock' => 'all',
        );

        register_post_type('pxlr-products', $args);
    }

    public function products_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
        $post = get_post($id);
        if ( is_object( $post ) ){
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'pxlr-products-category' );
            if( $terms ){
                return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
            }
            
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'pxlr-products-status' );
            if( $terms ){
                return str_replace( '%status%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
            }
        }
        return $post_link;
    }

    public function register_products_taxonomy()
    {   
        register_taxonomy(
            'pxlr-products-category',
            'pxlr-products',
            array(
                'label' => __('Categories Product', 'pxlr-products'),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'with_front' => false,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'rewrite'=> ['slug' => _x('products', 'Category Slug', 'pxlr-products'),
                                'with_front' => false,
                                'hierarchical' => true
                            ], 
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy(
            'pxlr-products-status',
            'pxlr-products',
            array(
                'label' => __('Status Product', 'pxlr-products'),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'with_front' => false,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'rewrite'=> ['slug' => _x('products/%category%', 'Status Slug', 'pxlr-products'),
                                'with_front' => false,
                                'hierarchical' => true
                            ], 
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
    }
}
```